# How to read in an edge list into a graph in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a edge list and I would like to convert it into a graph in networkx. Here is a the full edgelist which is in a file `cage12.edgelist`.

```
[[157, 428], [265, 720], [326, 721], [43, 461], [152, 649], [133, 489], [246, 697], [301, 450], [287, 718], [219, 601], [350, 476], [336, 480], [316, 459], [156, 595], [198, 676], [168, 496], [290, 488], [139, 635], [13, 414], [5, 383], [38, 505], [86, 639], [73, 608], [310, 696], [234, 565], [219, 395], [113, 652], [60, 570], [282, 620], [30, 481], [144, 517], [206, 440], [338, 711], [64, 582], [174, 673], [160, 511], [161, 487], [68, 594], [146, 388], [229, 545], [352, 693], [77, 621], [261, 720], [63, 580], [123, 403], [363, 384], [248, 704], [240, 415], [39, 507], [98, 651], [48, 534], [251, 714], [51, 409], [337, 616], [52, 546], [342, 716], [333, 433], [336, 534], [264, 648], [319, 471], [28, 475], [31, 483], [197, 444], [15, 421], [312, 713], [242, 672], [151, 538], [177, 676], [108, 661], [312, 551], [34, 493], [70, 601], [167, 523], [29, 476], [177, 499], [229, 431], [360, 700], [14, 419], [182, 394], [24, 457], [349, 582], [78, 625], [232, 663], [96, 602], [362, 367], [54, 553], [91, 644], [221, 589], [79, 453], [303, 492], [219, 539], [211, 495], [185, 520], [243, 680], [83, 370], [196, 563], [277, 414], [78, 417], [318, 496], [235, 665], [201, 537], [155, 565], [318, 526], [138, 400], [232, 459], [363, 694], [329, 445], [25, 463], [145, 550], [203, 587], [120, 495], [286, 700], [340, 505], [234, 682], [328, 449], [329, 469], [185, 422], [331, 726], [3, 376], [25, 464], [9, 398], [120, 391], [262, 637], [302, 702], [305, 701], [195, 682], [345, 614], [347, 615], [334, 501], [210, 392], [157, 580], [337, 589], [105, 503], [254, 720], [133, 636], [140, 628], [348, 503], [39, 397], [64, 369], [307, 694], [95, 575], [313, 444], [135, 558], [90, 608], [287, 517], [213, 519], [57, 560], [318, 547], [307, 440], [311, 576], [81, 634], [283, 419], [85, 638], [252, 718], [294, 624], [351, 609], [266, 677], [342, 502], [107, 584], [80, 630], [154, 523], [286, 435], [257, 660], [23, 453], [45, 525], [48, 393], [249, 709], [310, 452], [184, 547], [5, 384], [65, 586], [135, 540], [339, 586], [124, 467], [16, 428], [166, 550], [131, 576], [153, 440], [188, 535], [129, 618], [267, 676], [270, 656], [203, 671], [295, 696], [92, 551], [279, 592], [358, 378], [324, 523], [137, 661], [158, 502], [125, 609], [347, 555], [320, 605], [292, 424], [184, 561], [18, 434], [225, 447], [36, 497], [165, 664], [179, 532], [183, 633], [42, 517], [87, 418], [156, 396], [357, 695], [141, 577], [202, 420], [353, 397], [84, 637], [87, 640], [288, 709], [37, 502], [239, 548], [114, 606], [320, 572], [335, 556], [192, 400], [255, 666], [17, 431], [243, 592], [305, 628], [105, 599], [216, 452], [345, 557], [145, 598], [115, 471], [122, 431], [319, 700], [340, 535], [55, 555], [331, 425], [116, 555], [319, 443], [13, 413], [213, 581], [181, 390], [5, 382], [6, 388], [283, 699], [140, 475], [173, 541], [154, 625], [240, 497], [330, 453], [332, 417], [99, 438], [60, 571], [344, 478], [220, 427], [137, 553], [64, 583], [343, 608], [271, 690], [19, 439], [68, 595], [270, 638], [303, 546], [112, 573], [148, 481], [33, 490], [141, 532], [74, 611], [77, 620], [324, 718], [295, 432], [349, 706], [248, 705], [39, 506], [48, 535], [52, 547], [157, 535], [302, 634], [31, 482], [147, 651], [159, 645], [78, 623], [67, 592], [121, 661], [113, 435], [352, 725], [335, 702], [242, 479], [266, 668], [195, 408], [337, 703], [24, 458], [116, 443], [306, 495], [294, 594], [200, 489], [255, 684], [205, 477], [86, 414], [134, 447], [135, 455], [292, 408], [261, 674], [228, 683], [328, 726], [102, 386], [176, 410], [306, 712], [254, 679], [111, 395], [25, 462], [142, 616], [141, 416], [20, 441], [96, 506], [261, 683], [212, 673], [277, 422], [180, 505], [324, 553], [362, 698], [237, 574], [9, 397], [146, 526], [2, 372], [10, 404], [252, 697], [224, 533], [247, 701], [231, 679], [269, 652], [350, 500], [106, 536], [178, 624], [165, 374], [209, 626], [45, 449], [73, 373], [274, 430], [349, 561], [333, 727], [270, 647], [93, 524], [129, 648], [4, 377], [81, 633], [26, 465], [183, 398], [186, 414], [65, 381], [292, 695], [249, 707], [69, 413], [296, 482], [204, 608], [276, 568], [172, 487], [245, 695], [146, 659], [296, 539], [174, 630], [139, 432], [289, 694], [162, 444], [218, 634], [36, 453], [204, 492], [80, 631], [76, 617], [45, 524], [210, 483], [249, 708], [126, 585], [170, 462], [65, 585], [190, 368], [104, 572], [355, 691], [289, 436], [182, 606], [149, 655], [204, 404], [171, 670], [353, 727], [121, 627], [107, 509], [150, 604], [114, 504], [98, 587], [215, 480], [95, 533], [189, 688], [99, 485], [175, 674], [344, 508], [82, 563], [69, 598], [285, 569], [201, 396], [260, 678], [62, 469], [172, 576], [281, 484], [210, 575], [110, 657], [207, 675], [333, 409], [18, 435], [173, 672], [36, 498], [234, 439], [155, 660], [181, 680], [81, 441], [278, 712], [301, 692], [347, 705], [103, 434], [106, 466], [37, 501], [96, 649], [316, 698], [212, 432], [230, 494], [361, 365], [343, 709], [312, 518], [103, 656], [153, 490], [302, 607], [199, 632], [6, 386], [188, 564], [17, 430], [346, 530], [286, 407], [231, 583], [348, 527], [241, 451], [55, 554], [352, 697], [121, 423], [303, 710], [107, 660], [254, 670], [244, 689], [5, 381], [101, 382], [315, 545], [192, 629], [62, 576], [118, 621], [253, 671], [272, 486], [128, 379], [258, 649], [151, 657], [214, 590], [162, 544], [19, 438], [239, 562], [39, 508], [351, 704], [230, 403], [88, 542], [259, 673], [138, 622], [32, 485], [33, 489], [229, 559], [341, 554], [125, 654], [130, 507], [77, 405], [31, 484], [306, 549], [218, 387], [258, 640], [278, 489], [248, 706], [134, 653], [85, 422], [193, 522], [147, 392], [148, 634], [354, 393], [213, 680], [257, 723], [94, 479], [118, 639], [98, 446], [72, 605], [15, 423], [206, 566], [268, 654], [127, 371], [9, 400], [119, 597], [341, 587], [159, 478], [34, 491], [90, 643], [255, 721], [99, 614], [363, 368], [167, 666], [258, 658], [61, 574], [216, 569], [268, 645], [14, 417], [113, 474], [205, 617], [24, 459], [168, 667], [209, 388], [123, 641], [57, 389], [172, 671], [250, 689], [35, 496], [89, 642], [293, 509], [242, 471], [209, 678], [124, 637], [166, 665], [101, 593], [87, 500], [220, 686], [354, 728], [177, 402], [304, 470], [53, 550], [194, 614], [291, 618], [3, 373], [25, 461], [20, 442], [169, 475], [192, 687], [134, 582], [235, 515], [364, 370], [237, 684], [58, 564], [337, 562], [67, 591], [287, 487], [92, 394], [164, 370], [314, 579], [8, 393], [281, 544], [66, 588], [132, 477], [279, 703], [320, 708], [47, 531], [140, 412], [158, 408], [108, 611], [190, 578], [92, 596], [282, 563], [195, 546], [339, 559], [193, 584], [50, 540], [297, 570], [43, 519], [227, 482], [63, 445], [122, 603], [46, 528], [179, 570], [165, 627], [4, 378], [22, 452], [81, 632], [355, 390], [175, 558], [325, 727], [198, 623], [331, 401], [334, 528], [152, 583], [170, 529], [245, 694], [123, 531], [327, 723], [239, 669], [130, 419], [275, 537], [94, 629], [112, 415], [207, 501], [323, 575], [76, 618], [23, 455], [120, 564], [190, 486], [214, 504], [131, 427], [313, 460], [65, 584], [122, 651], [105, 658], [224, 571], [296, 515], [343, 584], [272, 540], [298, 442], [361, 377], [135, 646], [300, 711], [245, 696], [221, 521], [97, 539], [276, 702], [208, 668], [101, 654], [299, 631], [84, 617], [69, 597], [313, 695], [84, 374], [147, 568], [211, 416], [29, 377], [362, 387], [310, 468], [279, 619], [126, 459], [236, 383], [237, 391], [275, 483], [136, 496], [227, 580], [36, 499], [301, 454], [263, 659], [93, 623], [42, 515], [276, 622], [142, 452], [91, 569], [169, 668], [7, 389], [62, 575], [104, 530], [11, 405], [361, 389], [198, 474], [182, 544], [291, 597], [272, 513], [37, 500], [246, 700], [239, 407], [330, 465], [41, 514], [97, 442], [332, 429], [344, 717], [55, 556], [232, 622], [288, 623], [346, 506], [6, 387], [351, 588], [233, 671], [162, 559], [17, 429], [326, 719], [263, 641], [152, 514], [225, 681], [322, 699], [205, 685], [95, 402], [104, 426], [217, 666], [58, 433], [79, 627], [244, 690], [248, 693], [233, 506], [51, 543], [323, 632], [290, 713], [199, 513], [221, 670], [286, 415], [217, 367], [154, 376], [62, 577], [332, 728], [352, 689], [294, 564], [293, 542], [225, 473], [280, 423], [12, 409], [107, 470], [148, 636], [38, 503], [40, 413], [203, 436], [208, 372], [282, 707], [32, 486], [33, 488], [204, 681], [316, 467], [228, 512], [300, 552], [46, 369], [132, 411], [137, 592], [299, 577], [1, 367], [218, 674], [192, 510], [34, 465], [72, 606], [15, 422], [309, 714], [254, 688], [175, 406], [108, 462], [275, 711], [280, 698], [356, 375], [67, 425], [157, 637], [251, 693], [152, 472], [315, 497], [102, 620], [163, 366], [346, 473], [295, 416], [61, 573], [68, 401], [106, 659], [305, 574], [24, 460], [262, 655], [183, 682], [294, 705], [70, 599], [150, 420], [322, 463], [163, 484], [262, 646], [284, 541], [106, 557], [308, 573], [20, 444], [102, 655], [109, 567], [293, 485], [114, 642], [206, 665], [54, 551], [53, 549], [181, 490], [271, 402], [129, 522], [311, 705], [44, 521], [309, 524], [20, 443], [166, 430], [224, 673], [194, 498], [53, 445], [304, 462], [58, 565], [43, 520], [231, 423], [324, 493], [90, 488], [235, 375], [145, 643], [113, 630], [184, 418], [170, 669], [67, 590], [214, 468], [2, 370], [8, 394], [10, 402], [66, 589], [247, 703], [335, 583], [47, 530], [285, 708], [345, 707], [4, 380], [22, 450], [26, 468], [359, 376], [174, 514], [35, 495], [288, 566], [327, 725], [166, 555], [50, 541], [125, 439], [43, 518], [262, 723], [46, 529], [86, 578], [269, 643], [4, 379], [298, 690], [100, 378], [194, 428], [175, 553], [325, 726], [310, 448], [136, 642], [245, 693], [266, 721], [214, 684], [195, 554], [327, 722], [173, 382], [240, 677], [61, 457], [91, 497], [76, 619], [23, 454], [315, 521], [227, 379], [355, 398], [159, 424], [167, 582], [194, 672], [193, 424], [179, 438], [161, 647], [80, 465], [238, 518], [348, 479], [27, 469], [160, 589], [325, 728], [292, 428], [69, 596], [200, 572], [291, 567], [146, 619], [96, 406], [149, 404], [18, 433], [293, 714], [260, 687], [82, 366], [246, 698], [56, 557], [362, 395], [314, 630], [216, 674], [125, 483], [336, 710], [161, 464], [199, 376], [326, 725], [187, 458], [207, 456], [190, 670], [49, 538], [158, 601], [256, 635], [41, 513], [299, 703], [338, 504], [131, 528], [35, 441], [127, 594], [244, 692], [341, 708], [110, 387], [260, 669], [88, 641], [75, 397], [203, 525], [220, 613], [241, 664], [115, 588], [79, 626], [244, 691], [136, 571], [51, 542], [108, 482], [180, 442], [127, 552], [153, 613], [269, 722], [200, 679], [147, 493], [143, 468], [210, 688], [198, 460], [275, 510], [60, 421], [83, 636], [66, 393], [12, 410], [19, 440], [223, 662], [315, 715], [251, 713], [32, 487], [50, 433], [253, 662], [346, 715], [171, 594], [97, 560], [243, 443], [280, 431], [267, 667], [55, 365], [44, 437], [189, 454], [101, 548], [1, 366], [117, 612], [72, 607], [54, 457], [40, 509], [309, 491], [222, 551], [354, 369], [253, 680], [273, 571], [61, 572], [335, 610], [323, 599], [91, 390], [21, 447], [356, 383], [340, 718], [307, 456], [238, 688], [187, 686], [38, 385], [300, 498], [111, 549], [257, 651], [297, 621], [317, 626], [230, 616], [264, 722], [250, 710], [289, 404], [202, 549], [300, 525], [141, 646], [53, 548], [44, 522], [116, 655], [83, 545], [322, 455], [3, 375], [119, 546], [215, 448], [120, 649], [218, 509], [256, 722], [242, 625], [51, 544], [342, 481], [89, 515], [271, 410], [93, 646], [169, 621], [47, 532], [216, 528], [233, 598], [312, 494], [241, 568], [2, 371], [224, 463], [8, 395], [10, 403], [250, 712], [197, 666], [274, 434], [243, 500], [85, 473], [102, 521], [247, 702], [268, 724], [142, 656], [144, 586], [115, 516], [46, 527], [305, 601], [22, 451], [332, 405], [189, 508], [320, 629], [129, 399], [268, 636], [35, 494], [327, 724], [160, 460], [236, 676], [186, 615], [298, 438], [128, 570], [23, 456], [264, 639], [173, 603], [325, 725], [347, 585], [196, 531], [16, 425], [288, 590], [70, 449], [71, 461], [75, 615], [90, 450], [290, 512], [276, 595], [117, 486], [158, 653], [360, 399], [163, 573], [265, 672], [140, 654], [71, 603], [308, 706], [278, 516], [211, 611], [111, 591], [118, 525], [154, 641], [128, 492], [281, 514], [174, 386], [306, 522], [201, 602], [207, 596], [265, 681], [358, 382], [143, 648], [278, 543], [343, 560], [215, 620], [109, 367], [110, 519], [178, 446], [246, 699], [176, 675], [191, 677], [56, 558], [274, 691], [132, 643], [357, 392], [223, 595], [7, 391], [100, 494], [339, 613], [11, 407], [164, 600], [130, 600], [184, 683], [353, 385], [188, 687], [317, 578], [49, 537], [263, 650], [267, 719], [41, 512], [213, 412], [330, 728], [350, 714], [264, 657], [177, 612], [363, 400], [79, 628], [316, 439], [6, 385], [299, 604], [109, 498], [349, 612], [318, 717], [49, 421], [73, 610], [117, 451], [285, 617], [328, 437], [104, 657], [211, 663], [12, 412], [228, 399], [164, 663], [143, 541], [309, 548], [155, 380], [317, 709], [74, 612], [358, 386], [12, 411], [180, 597], [89, 581], [270, 723], [188, 450], [133, 463], [100, 566], [308, 603], [63, 579], [28, 473], [340, 475], [186, 493], [284, 511], [1, 365], [338, 477], [217, 488], [59, 567], [118, 375], [119, 383], [29, 478], [40, 510], [117, 645], [233, 467], [42, 401], [172, 378], [111, 647], [238, 435], [333, 421], [47, 381], [30, 479], [229, 687], [255, 675], [127, 638], [231, 524], [14, 420], [21, 446], [212, 552], [253, 719], [164, 538], [191, 543], [304, 466], [222, 419], [208, 605], [93, 398], [344, 529], [1, 368], [240, 610], [98, 512], [150, 644], [279, 565], [250, 711], [364, 374], [221, 411], [116, 537], [226, 371], [282, 596], [56, 377], [44, 523], [165, 511], [183, 517], [3, 374], [21, 448], [356, 699], [341, 611], [235, 631], [180, 679], [144, 448], [97, 650], [209, 516], [138, 520], [124, 543], [202, 557], [277, 418], [321, 550], [58, 563], [94, 647], [280, 403], [88, 454], [185, 684], [28, 365], [8, 396], [66, 587], [234, 527], [285, 593], [328, 461], [163, 662], [57, 562], [75, 616], [133, 615], [226, 542], [360, 371], [151, 562], [26, 466], [193, 662], [323, 707], [142, 484], [348, 713], [331, 413], [261, 665], [252, 716], [274, 426], [99, 652], [50, 539], [88, 554], [267, 685], [89, 458], [342, 532], [358, 692], [149, 529], [122, 501], [16, 426], [258, 724], [167, 434], [266, 686], [75, 614], [298, 446], [119, 656], [72, 437], [187, 618], [272, 710], [94, 410], [297, 706], [249, 697], [196, 464], [37, 373], [295, 412], [82, 491], [71, 602], [134, 510], [303, 519], [290, 536], [27, 471], [52, 469], [345, 581], [334, 474], [11, 408], [18, 436], [273, 625], [359, 696], [361, 726], [301, 458], [308, 633], [144, 640], [259, 721], [356, 391], [124, 561], [291, 704], [256, 653], [41, 425], [115, 635], [191, 599], [126, 644], [17, 432], [326, 720], [114, 407], [339, 701], [56, 559], [236, 536], [112, 534], [202, 664], [304, 691], [156, 652], [123, 579], [7, 390], [11, 406], [156, 547], [256, 644], [189, 591], [208, 540], [49, 536], [283, 411], [321, 716], [359, 396], [237, 485], [185, 588], [149, 574], [284, 717], [13, 415], [178, 478], [226, 604], [86, 527], [364, 690], [38, 504], [136, 368], [317, 602], [126, 513], [201, 686], [73, 609], [131, 650], [296, 715], [159, 631], [200, 380], [112, 659], [60, 569], [30, 480], [64, 581], [103, 476], [109, 640], [19, 437], [284, 490], [178, 677], [68, 593], [329, 727], [132, 633], [74, 613], [59, 568], [77, 622], [351, 558], [82, 635], [273, 598], [186, 685], [48, 533], [251, 715], [215, 667], [353, 373], [354, 381], [87, 605], [52, 545], [63, 578], [28, 474], [92, 645], [238, 586], [95, 648], [223, 455], [139, 508], [160, 658], [76, 429], [259, 682], [100, 653], [34, 492], [70, 600], [217, 577], [59, 566], [137, 384], [29, 477], [40, 511], [232, 476], [14, 418], [241, 530], [277, 692], [187, 481], [153, 638], [78, 624], [170, 567], [191, 384], [168, 609], [155, 499], [265, 663], [15, 424], [54, 552], [334, 712], [105, 430], [21, 445], [259, 664], [222, 556], [227, 675], [145, 372], [176, 526], [319, 451], [271, 406], [205, 472], [225, 619], [212, 560], [263, 724], [169, 470], [171, 502], [121, 480], [222, 678], [269, 661], [257, 642], [311, 627], [9, 399], [32, 429], [307, 472], [236, 607], [364, 366], [220, 491], [151, 456], [281, 716], [206, 534], [273, 701], [283, 427], [359, 380], [2, 369], [10, 401], [287, 538], [289, 420], [13, 416], [161, 610], [57, 561], [350, 533], [260, 719], [22, 449], [26, 467], [179, 678], [59, 409], [197, 507], [252, 717], [199, 669], [138, 650], [247, 689], [322, 447], [329, 457], [80, 629], [360, 379], [143, 556], [311, 606], [297, 591], [27, 472], [45, 526], [355, 394], [103, 626], [182, 681], [171, 466], [228, 628], [85, 632], [33, 405], [16, 427], [110, 624], [314, 704], [83, 590], [321, 520], [357, 372], [71, 604], [162, 639], [197, 593], [130, 660], [330, 441], [336, 507], [338, 531], [314, 600], [313, 464], [176, 585], [302, 580], [139, 607], [230, 668], [219, 685], [223, 503], [196, 683], [31, 417], [74, 385], [226, 667], [27, 470], [357, 388], [148, 436], [168, 426], [321, 499], [84, 518], [30, 389], [150, 505], [128, 658], [181, 579], [42, 516], [7, 392]]
```

I tried

```
fh = open("cage12.edgelist", 'rb') 
G=nx.read_edgelist(fh)
```

but it outputs `[...]  '[42,', '516],', '[7,', '392]]']) to dictionary.` which shows it is not parsing it correctly.

How can I read in this edgelist into a networkx graph?

Comment: It expects one pair of numbers per line in the file, not a nested list with `[[...]]` syntax.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks. Sadly this is the format I have it in. How can I input it?

Comment: Maybe try `from_edgelist` instead. But you need to convert the string representation of the nested list to an actual nested list. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your format no standard `networkx` read method exist, but you can easily manage this with the string method `split`:

```
import networkx as nx

string = [[157, 428], [265, 720], [326, 721], [43, 461], [152, 649], [133, 489], [246, 697], [301, 450], [287, 718], [219, 601], [350, 476], [336, 480], [316, 459], [156, 595], [198, 676], [168, 496], [290, 488], [139, 635], [13, 414], [5, 383], [38, 505], [86, 639], [73, 608], [310, 696], [234, 565], [219, 395], [113, 652], [60, 570], [282, 620], [30, 481], [144, 517], [206, 440], [338, 711], [64, 582], [174, 673], [160, 511], [161, 487], [68, 594], [146, 388], [229, 545], [352, 693], [77, 621], [261, 720], [63, 580], [123, 403], [363, 384], [248, 704], [240, 415], [39, 507], [98, 651], [48, 534], [251, 714], [51, 409], [337, 616], [52, 546], [342, 716], [333, 433], [336, 534], [264, 648], [319, 471], [28, 475], [31, 483], [197, 444], [15, 421], [312, 713], [242, 672], [151, 538], [177, 676], [108, 661], [312, 551], [34, 493], [70, 601], [167, 523], [29, 476], [177, 499], [229, 431], [360, 700], [14, 419], [182, 394], [24, 457], [349, 582], [78, 625], [232, 663], [96, 602], [362, 367], [54, 553], [91, 644], [221, 589], [79, 453], [303, 492], [219, 539], [211, 495], [185, 520], [243, 680], [83, 370], [196, 563], [277, 414], [78, 417], [318, 496], [235, 665], [201, 537], [155, 565], [318, 526], [138, 400], [232, 459], [363, 694], [329, 445], [25, 463], [145, 550], [203, 587], [120, 495], [286, 700], [340, 505], [234, 682], [328, 449], [329, 469], [185, 422], [331, 726], [3, 376], [25, 464], [9, 398], [120, 391], [262, 637], [302, 702], [305, 701], [195, 682], [345, 614], [347, 615], [334, 501], [210, 392], [157, 580], [337, 589], [105, 503], [254, 720], [133, 636], [140, 628], [348, 503], [39, 397], [64, 369], [307, 694], [95, 575], [313, 444], [135, 558], [90, 608], [287, 517], [213, 519], [57, 560], [318, 547], [307, 440], [311, 576], [81, 634], [283, 419], [85, 638], [252, 718], [294, 624], [351, 609], [266, 677], [342, 502], [107, 584], [80, 630], [154, 523], [286, 435], [257, 660], [23, 453], [45, 525], [48, 393], [249, 709], [310, 452], [184, 547], [5, 384], [65, 586], [135, 540], [339, 586], [124, 467], [16, 428], [166, 550], [131, 576], [153, 440], [188, 535], [129, 618], [267, 676], [270, 656], [203, 671], [295, 696], [92, 551], [279, 592], [358, 378], [324, 523], [137, 661], [158, 502], [125, 609], [347, 555], [320, 605], [292, 424], [184, 561], [18, 434], [225, 447], [36, 497], [165, 664], [179, 532], [183, 633], [42, 517], [87, 418], [156, 396], [357, 695], [141, 577], [202, 420], [353, 397], [84, 637], [87, 640], [288, 709], [37, 502], [239, 548], [114, 606], [320, 572], [335, 556], [192, 400], [255, 666], [17, 431], [243, 592], [305, 628], [105, 599], [216, 452], [345, 557], [145, 598], [115, 471], [122, 431], [319, 700], [340, 535], [55, 555], [331, 425], [116, 555], [319, 443], [13, 413], [213, 581], [181, 390], [5, 382], [6, 388], [283, 699], [140, 475], [173, 541], [154, 625], [240, 497], [330, 453], [332, 417], [99, 438], [60, 571], [344, 478], [220, 427], [137, 553], [64, 583], [343, 608], [271, 690], [19, 439], [68, 595], [270, 638], [303, 546], [112, 573], [148, 481], [33, 490], [141, 532], [74, 611], [77, 620], [324, 718], [295, 432], [349, 706], [248, 705], [39, 506], [48, 535], [52, 547], [157, 535], [302, 634], [31, 482], [147, 651], [159, 645], [78, 623], [67, 592], [121, 661], [113, 435], [352, 725], [335, 702], [242, 479], [266, 668], [195, 408], [337, 703], [24, 458], [116, 443], [306, 495], [294, 594], [200, 489], [255, 684], [205, 477], [86, 414], [134, 447], [135, 455], [292, 408], [261, 674], [228, 683], [328, 726], [102, 386], [176, 410], [306, 712], [254, 679], [111, 395], [25, 462], [142, 616], [141, 416], [20, 441], [96, 506], [261, 683], [212, 673], [277, 422], [180, 505], [324, 553], [362, 698], [237, 574], [9, 397], [146, 526], [2, 372], [10, 404], [252, 697], [224, 533], [247, 701], [231, 679], [269, 652], [350, 500], [106, 536], [178, 624], [165, 374], [209, 626], [45, 449], [73, 373], [274, 430], [349, 561], [333, 727], [270, 647], [93, 524], [129, 648], [4, 377], [81, 633], [26, 465], [183, 398], [186, 414], [65, 381], [292, 695], [249, 707], [69, 413], [296, 482], [204, 608], [276, 568], [172, 487], [245, 695], [146, 659], [296, 539], [174, 630], [139, 432], [289, 694], [162, 444], [218, 634], [36, 453], [204, 492], [80, 631], [76, 617], [45, 524], [210, 483], [249, 708], [126, 585], [170, 462], [65, 585], [190, 368], [104, 572], [355, 691], [289, 436], [182, 606], [149, 655], [204, 404], [171, 670], [353, 727], [121, 627], [107, 509], [150, 604], [114, 504], [98, 587], [215, 480], [95, 533], [189, 688], [99, 485], [175, 674], [344, 508], [82, 563], [69, 598], [285, 569], [201, 396], [260, 678], [62, 469], [172, 576], [281, 484], [210, 575], [110, 657], [207, 675], [333, 409], [18, 435], [173, 672], [36, 498], [234, 439], [155, 660], [181, 680], [81, 441], [278, 712], [301, 692], [347, 705], [103, 434], [106, 466], [37, 501], [96, 649], [316, 698], [212, 432], [230, 494], [361, 365], [343, 709], [312, 518], [103, 656], [153, 490], [302, 607], [199, 632], [6, 386], [188, 564], [17, 430], [346, 530], [286, 407], [231, 583], [348, 527], [241, 451], [55, 554], [352, 697], [121, 423], [303, 710], [107, 660], [254, 670], [244, 689], [5, 381], [101, 382], [315, 545], [192, 629], [62, 576], [118, 621], [253, 671], [272, 486], [128, 379], [258, 649], [151, 657], [214, 590], [162, 544], [19, 438], [239, 562], [39, 508], [351, 704], [230, 403], [88, 542], [259, 673], [138, 622], [32, 485], [33, 489], [229, 559], [341, 554], [125, 654], [130, 507], [77, 405], [31, 484], [306, 549], [218, 387], [258, 640], [278, 489], [248, 706], [134, 653], [85, 422], [193, 522], [147, 392], [148, 634], [354, 393], [213, 680], [257, 723], [94, 479], [118, 639], [98, 446], [72, 605], [15, 423], [206, 566], [268, 654], [127, 371], [9, 400], [119, 597], [341, 587], [159, 478], [34, 491], [90, 643], [255, 721], [99, 614], [363, 368], [167, 666], [258, 658], [61, 574], [216, 569], [268, 645], [14, 417], [113, 474], [205, 617], [24, 459], [168, 667], [209, 388], [123, 641], [57, 389], [172, 671], [250, 689], [35, 496], [89, 642], [293, 509], [242, 471], [209, 678], [124, 637], [166, 665], [101, 593], [87, 500], [220, 686], [354, 728], [177, 402], [304, 470], [53, 550], [194, 614], [291, 618], [3, 373], [25, 461], [20, 442], [169, 475], [192, 687], [134, 582], [235, 515], [364, 370], [237, 684], [58, 564], [337, 562], [67, 591], [287, 487], [92, 394], [164, 370], [314, 579], [8, 393], [281, 544], [66, 588], [132, 477], [279, 703], [320, 708], [47, 531], [140, 412], [158, 408], [108, 611], [190, 578], [92, 596], [282, 563], [195, 546], [339, 559], [193, 584], [50, 540], [297, 570], [43, 519], [227, 482], [63, 445], [122, 603], [46, 528], [179, 570], [165, 627], [4, 378], [22, 452], [81, 632], [355, 390], [175, 558], [325, 727], [198, 623], [331, 401], [334, 528], [152, 583], [170, 529], [245, 694], [123, 531], [327, 723], [239, 669], [130, 419], [275, 537], [94, 629], [112, 415], [207, 501], [323, 575], [76, 618], [23, 455], [120, 564], [190, 486], [214, 504], [131, 427], [313, 460], [65, 584], [122, 651], [105, 658], [224, 571], [296, 515], [343, 584], [272, 540], [298, 442], [361, 377], [135, 646], [300, 711], [245, 696], [221, 521], [97, 539], [276, 702], [208, 668], [101, 654], [299, 631], [84, 617], [69, 597], [313, 695], [84, 374], [147, 568], [211, 416], [29, 377], [362, 387], [310, 468], [279, 619], [126, 459], [236, 383], [237, 391], [275, 483], [136, 496], [227, 580], [36, 499], [301, 454], [263, 659], [93, 623], [42, 515], [276, 622], [142, 452], [91, 569], [169, 668], [7, 389], [62, 575], [104, 530], [11, 405], [361, 389], [198, 474], [182, 544], [291, 597], [272, 513], [37, 500], [246, 700], [239, 407], [330, 465], [41, 514], [97, 442], [332, 429], [344, 717], [55, 556], [232, 622], [288, 623], [346, 506], [6, 387], [351, 588], [233, 671], [162, 559], [17, 429], [326, 719], [263, 641], [152, 514], [225, 681], [322, 699], [205, 685], [95, 402], [104, 426], [217, 666], [58, 433], [79, 627], [244, 690], [248, 693], [233, 506], [51, 543], [323, 632], [290, 713], [199, 513], [221, 670], [286, 415], [217, 367], [154, 376], [62, 577], [332, 728], [352, 689], [294, 564], [293, 542], [225, 473], [280, 423], [12, 409], [107, 470], [148, 636], [38, 503], [40, 413], [203, 436], [208, 372], [282, 707], [32, 486], [33, 488], [204, 681], [316, 467], [228, 512], [300, 552], [46, 369], [132, 411], [137, 592], [299, 577], [1, 367], [218, 674], [192, 510], [34, 465], [72, 606], [15, 422], [309, 714], [254, 688], [175, 406], [108, 462], [275, 711], [280, 698], [356, 375], [67, 425], [157, 637], [251, 693], [152, 472], [315, 497], [102, 620], [163, 366], [346, 473], [295, 416], [61, 573], [68, 401], [106, 659], [305, 574], [24, 460], [262, 655], [183, 682], [294, 705], [70, 599], [150, 420], [322, 463], [163, 484], [262, 646], [284, 541], [106, 557], [308, 573], [20, 444], [102, 655], [109, 567], [293, 485], [114, 642], [206, 665], [54, 551], [53, 549], [181, 490], [271, 402], [129, 522], [311, 705], [44, 521], [309, 524], [20, 443], [166, 430], [224, 673], [194, 498], [53, 445], [304, 462], [58, 565], [43, 520], [231, 423], [324, 493], [90, 488], [235, 375], [145, 643], [113, 630], [184, 418], [170, 669], [67, 590], [214, 468], [2, 370], [8, 394], [10, 402], [66, 589], [247, 703], [335, 583], [47, 530], [285, 708], [345, 707], [4, 380], [22, 450], [26, 468], [359, 376], [174, 514], [35, 495], [288, 566], [327, 725], [166, 555], [50, 541], [125, 439], [43, 518], [262, 723], [46, 529], [86, 578], [269, 643], [4, 379], [298, 690], [100, 378], [194, 428], [175, 553], [325, 726], [310, 448], [136, 642], [245, 693], [266, 721], [214, 684], [195, 554], [327, 722], [173, 382], [240, 677], [61, 457], [91, 497], [76, 619], [23, 454], [315, 521], [227, 379], [355, 398], [159, 424], [167, 582], [194, 672], [193, 424], [179, 438], [161, 647], [80, 465], [238, 518], [348, 479], [27, 469], [160, 589], [325, 728], [292, 428], [69, 596], [200, 572], [291, 567], [146, 619], [96, 406], [149, 404], [18, 433], [293, 714], [260, 687], [82, 366], [246, 698], [56, 557], [362, 395], [314, 630], [216, 674], [125, 483], [336, 710], [161, 464], [199, 376], [326, 725], [187, 458], [207, 456], [190, 670], [49, 538], [158, 601], [256, 635], [41, 513], [299, 703], [338, 504], [131, 528], [35, 441], [127, 594], [244, 692], [341, 708], [110, 387], [260, 669], [88, 641], [75, 397], [203, 525], [220, 613], [241, 664], [115, 588], [79, 626], [244, 691], [136, 571], [51, 542], [108, 482], [180, 442], [127, 552], [153, 613], [269, 722], [200, 679], [147, 493], [143, 468], [210, 688], [198, 460], [275, 510], [60, 421], [83, 636], [66, 393], [12, 410], [19, 440], [223, 662], [315, 715], [251, 713], [32, 487], [50, 433], [253, 662], [346, 715], [171, 594], [97, 560], [243, 443], [280, 431], [267, 667], [55, 365], [44, 437], [189, 454], [101, 548], [1, 366], [117, 612], [72, 607], [54, 457], [40, 509], [309, 491], [222, 551], [354, 369], [253, 680], [273, 571], [61, 572], [335, 610], [323, 599], [91, 390], [21, 447], [356, 383], [340, 718], [307, 456], [238, 688], [187, 686], [38, 385], [300, 498], [111, 549], [257, 651], [297, 621], [317, 626], [230, 616], [264, 722], [250, 710], [289, 404], [202, 549], [300, 525], [141, 646], [53, 548], [44, 522], [116, 655], [83, 545], [322, 455], [3, 375], [119, 546], [215, 448], [120, 649], [218, 509], [256, 722], [242, 625], [51, 544], [342, 481], [89, 515], [271, 410], [93, 646], [169, 621], [47, 532], [216, 528], [233, 598], [312, 494], [241, 568], [2, 371], [224, 463], [8, 395], [10, 403], [250, 712], [197, 666], [274, 434], [243, 500], [85, 473], [102, 521], [247, 702], [268, 724], [142, 656], [144, 586], [115, 516], [46, 527], [305, 601], [22, 451], [332, 405], [189, 508], [320, 629], [129, 399], [268, 636], [35, 494], [327, 724], [160, 460], [236, 676], [186, 615], [298, 438], [128, 570], [23, 456], [264, 639], [173, 603], [325, 725], [347, 585], [196, 531], [16, 425], [288, 590], [70, 449], [71, 461], [75, 615], [90, 450], [290, 512], [276, 595], [117, 486], [158, 653], [360, 399], [163, 573], [265, 672], [140, 654], [71, 603], [308, 706], [278, 516], [211, 611], [111, 591], [118, 525], [154, 641], [128, 492], [281, 514], [174, 386], [306, 522], [201, 602], [207, 596], [265, 681], [358, 382], [143, 648], [278, 543], [343, 560], [215, 620], [109, 367], [110, 519], [178, 446], [246, 699], [176, 675], [191, 677], [56, 558], [274, 691], [132, 643], [357, 392], [223, 595], [7, 391], [100, 494], [339, 613], [11, 407], [164, 600], [130, 600], [184, 683], [353, 385], [188, 687], [317, 578], [49, 537], [263, 650], [267, 719], [41, 512], [213, 412], [330, 728], [350, 714], [264, 657], [177, 612], [363, 400], [79, 628], [316, 439], [6, 385], [299, 604], [109, 498], [349, 612], [318, 717], [49, 421], [73, 610], [117, 451], [285, 617], [328, 437], [104, 657], [211, 663], [12, 412], [228, 399], [164, 663], [143, 541], [309, 548], [155, 380], [317, 709], [74, 612], [358, 386], [12, 411], [180, 597], [89, 581], [270, 723], [188, 450], [133, 463], [100, 566], [308, 603], [63, 579], [28, 473], [340, 475], [186, 493], [284, 511], [1, 365], [338, 477], [217, 488], [59, 567], [118, 375], [119, 383], [29, 478], [40, 510], [117, 645], [233, 467], [42, 401], [172, 378], [111, 647], [238, 435], [333, 421], [47, 381], [30, 479], [229, 687], [255, 675], [127, 638], [231, 524], [14, 420], [21, 446], [212, 552], [253, 719], [164, 538], [191, 543], [304, 466], [222, 419], [208, 605], [93, 398], [344, 529], [1, 368], [240, 610], [98, 512], [150, 644], [279, 565], [250, 711], [364, 374], [221, 411], [116, 537], [226, 371], [282, 596], [56, 377], [44, 523], [165, 511], [183, 517], [3, 374], [21, 448], [356, 699], [341, 611], [235, 631], [180, 679], [144, 448], [97, 650], [209, 516], [138, 520], [124, 543], [202, 557], [277, 418], [321, 550], [58, 563], [94, 647], [280, 403], [88, 454], [185, 684], [28, 365], [8, 396], [66, 587], [234, 527], [285, 593], [328, 461], [163, 662], [57, 562], [75, 616], [133, 615], [226, 542], [360, 371], [151, 562], [26, 466], [193, 662], [323, 707], [142, 484], [348, 713], [331, 413], [261, 665], [252, 716], [274, 426], [99, 652], [50, 539], [88, 554], [267, 685], [89, 458], [342, 532], [358, 692], [149, 529], [122, 501], [16, 426], [258, 724], [167, 434], [266, 686], [75, 614], [298, 446], [119, 656], [72, 437], [187, 618], [272, 710], [94, 410], [297, 706], [249, 697], [196, 464], [37, 373], [295, 412], [82, 491], [71, 602], [134, 510], [303, 519], [290, 536], [27, 471], [52, 469], [345, 581], [334, 474], [11, 408], [18, 436], [273, 625], [359, 696], [361, 726], [301, 458], [308, 633], [144, 640], [259, 721], [356, 391], [124, 561], [291, 704], [256, 653], [41, 425], [115, 635], [191, 599], [126, 644], [17, 432], [326, 720], [114, 407], [339, 701], [56, 559], [236, 536], [112, 534], [202, 664], [304, 691], [156, 652], [123, 579], [7, 390], [11, 406], [156, 547], [256, 644], [189, 591], [208, 540], [49, 536], [283, 411], [321, 716], [359, 396], [237, 485], [185, 588], [149, 574], [284, 717], [13, 415], [178, 478], [226, 604], [86, 527], [364, 690], [38, 504], [136, 368], [317, 602], [126, 513], [201, 686], [73, 609], [131, 650], [296, 715], [159, 631], [200, 380], [112, 659], [60, 569], [30, 480], [64, 581], [103, 476], [109, 640], [19, 437], [284, 490], [178, 677], [68, 593], [329, 727], [132, 633], [74, 613], [59, 568], [77, 622], [351, 558], [82, 635], [273, 598], [186, 685], [48, 533], [251, 715], [215, 667], [353, 373], [354, 381], [87, 605], [52, 545], [63, 578], [28, 474], [92, 645], [238, 586], [95, 648], [223, 455], [139, 508], [160, 658], [76, 429], [259, 682], [100, 653], [34, 492], [70, 600], [217, 577], [59, 566], [137, 384], [29, 477], [40, 511], [232, 476], [14, 418], [241, 530], [277, 692], [187, 481], [153, 638], [78, 624], [170, 567], [191, 384], [168, 609], [155, 499], [265, 663], [15, 424], [54, 552], [334, 712], [105, 430], [21, 445], [259, 664], [222, 556], [227, 675], [145, 372], [176, 526], [319, 451], [271, 406], [205, 472], [225, 619], [212, 560], [263, 724], [169, 470], [171, 502], [121, 480], [222, 678], [269, 661], [257, 642], [311, 627], [9, 399], [32, 429], [307, 472], [236, 607], [364, 366], [220, 491], [151, 456], [281, 716], [206, 534], [273, 701], [283, 427], [359, 380], [2, 369], [10, 401], [287, 538], [289, 420], [13, 416], [161, 610], [57, 561], [350, 533], [260, 719], [22, 449], [26, 467], [179, 678], [59, 409], [197, 507], [252, 717], [199, 669], [138, 650], [247, 689], [322, 447], [329, 457], [80, 629], [360, 379], [143, 556], [311, 606], [297, 591], [27, 472], [45, 526], [355, 394], [103, 626], [182, 681], [171, 466], [228, 628], [85, 632], [33, 405], [16, 427], [110, 624], [314, 704], [83, 590], [321, 520], [357, 372], [71, 604], [162, 639], [197, 593], [130, 660], [330, 441], [336, 507], [338, 531], [314, 600], [313, 464], [176, 585], [302, 580], [139, 607], [230, 668], [219, 685], [223, 503], [196, 683], [31, 417], [74, 385], [226, 667], [27, 470], [357, 388], [148, 436], [168, 426], [321, 499], [84, 518], [30, 389], [150, 505], [128, 658], [181, 579], [42, 516], [7, 392]]

# To test file reading and writing
#
# with open("edgelist", "w") as file:
#     file.write(str(string))
# 
# with open("edgelist", "r") as file:
#     data = file.read()

# or simply use the given data as one large string
data = str(string)

graph = nx.Graph()
# we skip the first two [[ and the last ]] and separate the tuples
for edges in data[2:-2].split("], ["):
    # now we only need to separate the left and the right node 
    raw_u, raw_v = edges.split(", ")
    # and now we convert them to ints
    u = int(raw_u)
    v = int(raw_v)

    graph.add_edge(u, v)

print(graph.edges())
```

Comment: There is a typo in `u = int(raw_v)`